# Expected number of cuts before a stick is halved

Tags: probability, expected-value

A stick of unit length is put horizontally from left to right. Cut this stick at a uniformly randomly chosen position at each step and keep the left remaining part. Keep cutting until the length of the remaining part is smaller than 1/2 of the original length. Find the expected number of cuts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community ---  Hi Bot. It's amazing how your comments are so often in error saying of a question that "it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking." Seriously to the actual person who's the source of this automatic comment: Why not go to the trouble of generating a variety of such auto-responses and try to give one that's relevant to a given question?

Answer (score 3):

Let $E_{r}$ be the expected number of cuts before the remainder is smaller than $r$ times the original length. We have the following recurrence relationship:

$$E_{r} = r  + \int_{r}^{1} (1+ E_{(r/x)}) \;dx= \\=1 + \int_{r}^{1}  E_{(r/x)}  \;dx $$
With $E_{0} = \infty $ and $E_{1} = 1$.

Explanation: Assuming the first cut gives a remainder of length $r$ or less  gives expected number of cuts $1$. Assuming the remainder is of length  $x \in [r,1]$ gives the expected number of cuts $1$ + the number of cuts required to reach $r/x$ times the remaining length.

This gives us: $$E_{r} = 1 - \log(r)\\ E_{\frac{1}{2}} = 1 + \log(2)$$

---

Proof that the solution $E_{r} = 1-\log(r)$ is uniquely determined by the recurrence and constraints:

Let $F_{r}$ be defined by $F_{\log(r)} = E_{r}$. We have $$F_{\log(r)} = 1 + \int_{r}^{1}  F_{\log(r)-\log(x)} dx $$ By changing variables as: $\log(r)\rightarrow r$, $\log(x)\rightarrow x\;$
(or  $r\rightarrow e^r$, $x\rightarrow e^x$) the equation becomes:

$$F_{r} = 1 + \int_{r}^{0}  e^x F_{(r-x)} dx $$
An additional change of $x \rightarrow (r-x)$ gives:
$$F_{r} = 1 + \int_{0}^{r}  -F_{x} \;e^{r-x} \; dx $$
with our constraints becoming $F_{-\infty} = \infty$ and $F_{0} = 1$. Assume this has more than one solution (as our solution gives $F_{r} = 1 - r$). Then the difference between the two solutions satisfies:
$$D_{r} =  \int_{0}^{r}  -D_{x} \;e^{r-x} \; dx \\
D_0 = 0 $$
Differentiating the equation by $r$ we get:

$$D_{r}' = -D_r \; e^{r-r} +  \int_{0}^{r}  -D_{x} \;e^{r-x} \; dx = \\=-D_{r} + D_{r} = 0 $$
From this we get $D_{r} = c$, which combined with $D_{0} = 0 $ gives $D_{r} = 0$. Therefore, our solution is unique.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the remaining part is the product $Z_n = \prod_{k=1}^n X_k$ of i.i.d. random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$, each of which is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, and $N=\min\{n \geq 1 : Z_n < 1/2\}$ is a stopping time with respect to the natural filtration.

Then

- $Z_N$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1/2)$
- $\log(X_n)$ is integrable with expected value $-1$
- $N \leq \min\{n \geq 1 : X_n < 1/2\}$ which is a geometric random variable and therefore integrable.

The above justifies the use of Wald's equation for stopping times, so that $$\mathbb{E}[N] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\log(Z_N)]}{\mathbb{E}[\log(X_1)]} = -2\int_0^{1/2}\log x\,dx = 1 + \log(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

The simulation results (with `R`) also support the above results:

```
set.seed(1)
cuts <- replicate(100000, 
               {
                 x <- 1
                 i <- 0
                 while (x >= 1/2) {
                   x <- runif(1, 0, x) # keep the left part
                   i <- i + 1                   
                 }
                 i
               }
               )
 mean(cuts)
 # [1] 1.69461
 1 + log(2)
 # [1] 1.693147
```

It's interesting to observe how the distribution of cuts looks like:

```
hist(cuts)
```

[image]

Comment: Your histogram only has one observation, which is why it may seem uniform. Clearly the number of cuts is an unbounded variable, so it cannot be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for each $\tau\in\left[0,1\right]$ we can consider the expected number of cuts required to reduce a stick to (strictly) less than the proportion $\tau$ of its original length. We claim that this is none other than $1+\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)$.

---

Consider the space $\mathbb{S} := \left[0,1\right]^{\omega}$ sequences of points of $\left[0,1\right]$  equipped with the standard product Borel (probability) measure $\mu_{\mathbb{S}}$. The expected value in question is $$\sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}}\text{N}\int_{\left(x_{1},\ x_{2},\ \dots\right)\ \in\ \mathbb{S}}1_{x_{1}\cdot\cdots\cdot x_{\text{N}-1}\ \geq\ \tau\ >\ x_{1}\cdot\cdots\cdot x_{\text{N}}}\text{d}\mu_{\mathbb{S}}\text{.}$$ $\mathbb{S}$ admits a(n A.E. continuously differentiable) parametrization by the space $\mathbb{T}$ of *decreasing* sequences $\left(t_{0} = 1,\ t_{1},\ t_{2},\ \dots\right)$ of points of $\left[0,1\right]$, namely as prescribed by the map $$\mathscr{s}\ \colon\ \left(t_{0}= 1,\ t_{1},\ t_{2},\ \dots\right)\ \in\ \mathbb{T}^{\omega}\ \mapsto\ \left(\frac{t_{1}}{t_{0}},\ \frac{t_{2}}{t_{1}},\ \dots\right)\ \in\ \mathbb{S}^{\omega}\text{.}$$ In particular, $\mathbb{T}$ can be equipped with the pullback $\mathscr{s}^{-1}\mu_{\mathbb{S}}$ of $\mu_{\mathbb{S}}$ along $\mathscr{s}$, and it's not hard to see that $$\text{d}\left(\mathscr{s}^{-1}\mu_{\mathbb{S}}\right)\ =\ \frac{\text{d}t_{1}}{t_{0}}\frac{\text{d}t_{2}}{t_{1}}\cdots$$ on the boxes that generate the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{T}$. Thus the desired expected value is
\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}}\text{N}\int_{\left(x_{1},\ x_{2},\ \dots\right)\ \in\ \mathbb{S}}1_{x_{1}\cdot\cdots\cdot x_{\text{N}-1}\ \geq\ \tau\ >\ x_{1}\cdot\cdots\cdot x_{\text{N}}}\text{d}\mu_{\mathbb{S}}\\
    &=\ \sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}}\text{N}\int_{\left(t_{0}=1,\ t_{1},\ t_{2},\ \dots\right)\ \in\ \mathbb{T}}1_{t_{\text{N}-1}\ \geq\ \tau\ >\ t_{\text{N}}}\text{d}\left(\mathscr{s}^{-1}\mu_{\mathbb{S}}\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}}\text{N} \int_{t_{1}\ =\ \tau}^{1}\cdots\int_{t_{\text{N}-1}\ =\ \tau}^{t_{\text{N}-2}}\int_{t_{\text{N}}\ =\ 0}^{\tau} \frac{\text{d}t_{\text{N}}}{t_{\text{N}-1}}\cdots\frac{\text{d}t_{2}}{t_{1}}\ \text{d}t_{1}\\
    &=\ \sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}}\text{N} \int_{t_{1}\ =\ \tau}^{1}\cdots\int_{t_{\text{N}-1}\ =\ \tau}^{t_{\text{N}-2}}\int_{t_{\text{N}}\ =\ 0}^{\tau} \text{d}t_{\text{N}}\ \text{d}\left(\log\left(t_{\text{N}-1}\right)\right)\cdots\text{d}\left(\log\left(t_{1}\right)\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}} \text{N}\tau\int_{t_{\text{N}-1}\ =\ \tau}^{1}\int_{t_{\text{N}-2}\ =\ t_{\text{N}-1}}^{1}\cdots\int_{t_{1}\ =\ t_{2}}^{1} \ \text{d}\left(\log\left(t_{1}\right)\right)\cdots\text{d}\left(\log\left(t_{\text{N}-2}\right)\right)\text{d}\left(\log\left(t_{\text{N}-1}\right)\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}} \text{N}\tau\ \frac{\left(-\log\left(\tau\right)\right)^{\text{N}-1}}{\left(\text{N}-1\right)!}\\
    &=\ \tau\sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 1}}\frac{\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)^{\text{N}-1}}{\left(\text{N}-1\right)!}\ +\ \log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)\ \tau\sum_{\text{N}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq\ 2}}\frac{\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)^{\text{N}-2}}{\left(\text{N}-2\right)!}\\
    &=\ \left(1+\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)\right)\ \tau\ \sum_{\text{k}\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} \frac{\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)^{\text{k}}}{\text{k}!}\\
    &=\ \left(1+\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)\right)\ \tau\ e^{\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)}\\
    &=\ 1+\log\left(\tau^{-1}\right)
\end{align*}
as claimed $\blacksquare$